# Get Last Record of same ColumnID

Tags: sql, t-sql, filter

i am currently stuck on the following Task:

i have a table that Looks similiar to this one

```
| TableID | EntityID | InvoiceAmount |    Date    |
|     1   |   46     | 300 000       | 14-01-2014 |
|     2   |  232     | 2456,63       | 17-01-2014 |
|     3   |   46     | 400 000       | 22-01-2014 |
|     4   |  232     | 333 000       | 31-01-2014 |
|     5   |   12     | 124           | 11-01-2014 |
|     6   |   46     | 300 000       | 31-01-2014 |
```

What i Need is the last Invoice amount by EntityID according to the Date Column,
so in the Case of EntityID 46 this would be the 31-01-2014, and the Value of the Entity would be: 300 000.

Question: Is there a way to do this in SQL or what other Option do i have ?

thanks a lot in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest on sql-server >= 2005 is using a ranking function like `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT TableID,EntityID,InvoiceAmount,Date,
        RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY EntityID ORDER BY Date DESC)
    FROM dbo.TableName
)
SELECT InvoiceAmount FROM CTE 
WHERE RN = 1 
-- AND EntityID = 46
```

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d698a/2/0)</kbd>